# "Can I pick up his belongings when we go back to work in September?" OR "Can I pick up his belongings in September when we go back to work?"

Tags: grammar

I worked in a school but I'm not a teacher; my kid is a student in that school. Due to the pandemic, the school was closed but students' belongings and artwork were left in classrooms.

Yesterday, I received emails from the principal and teacher asking parents to pick up students' stuff on a specific date. Different classrooms were assigned on different dates for parents to pick up. As I will come back to work in September for the next school year, I want to email the teacher (my coworker) if I can pick up my kid's belongings in September when the next school year starts.

I do not know how I can express my idea of picking up the belongings when I go back to work. Which of the following is correct?

> Can I pick up his belongings when we go back to work in September?
>   Can I pick up his belongings in September when we go back to work?"

Comment: I prefer the first wording, but both sentences sound fine to me except that it should be *belongings* with an *s*, not *belonging*.

Comment: There is a slight difference. In the first one, "in September" modifies "when we go back to work". In the second, "in September" modifies "pick up his belongings".  This doesn't make any difference to the meaning in this sentence, so you can use either one.